# OWL API renamed entity from imported ontology

Tags: java, owl-api

I have the ontology A which is imported in B. I would like to rename an entity, so I write:

```
OWLEntityRenamer renamer = new OWLEntityRenamer(manager, Collections.singleton(A));        
Map<OWLEntity, IRI> entity2IRIMap = new HashMap<>();             
entity2IRIMap.put(datafactory.getOWLNamedIndividual(iriBase+"Skyfos"), IRI.create(iriBase+"Skyphos"));       
manager.applyChanges(renamer.changeIRI(entity2IRIMap)); 
manager.save(A);
manager.save(B);
```

Now, the entity is correctly renamed in A, but in B I have both the entities. In particular in B, each object-property that uses "Skyfos" continues to use "Skyfos" instead of "Skyphos".
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that OWLEntityRenamer requires all the ontology to be modified.

Comment: This is not an answer to your own question. Either edit your question, or add it as a comment.

Comment: My solution: 
        Set<OWLOntology> set=new HashSet<OWLOntology>();
        set.add(A);
        set.add(B);
        OWLEntityRenamer renamer = new OWLEntityRenamer(manager, set );

Answer (score 1):

You have passed only ontology A to the renamer. If B already uses the old IRI, it won't be changed. Pass both ontologies to the renamer and try again.